# How to draw polyline in multiple location marker in [ios 7]?

Tags: ios, ios7, mkmapview

In ios6 SDK deprecated some methods which is used to draw poly line.

Multiple Marker which i put on map

i want to draw line between each Marker.

```
1)  25.8076731   84.6896679        
2)  16.85438     74.564171    
3)  17.691401    74.000938    
4)  18.5291222   73.8736998
5)  18.74749     73.403442
```

i use some of following code: 
1) delegate method **rendererForOverlay:**
2)

```
 CLLocationCoordinate2D  coord;
 coord.latitude =lat.doubleValue;
 coord.longitude =lng.doubleValue;
 MapViewAnnotation *annotation =[[MapViewAnnotation alloc]initWithTitle:titles AndCoordinate:coord];
 [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
```

3)

```
  MKPolyline *polyline = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coordinates count:i];
  [self.mapView addOverlay:polyline];
```

what was the exact coding?

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 0):

Check the link below.

http://www.shawngrimes.me/2011/04/adding-polygon-map-overlays/

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: that link is right !! and code also be right on given link this code for ios6 i want to know about how to done with the ios7 methods?

@Fahim Parker

Comment: @user3400485 : It works in iOS 7 too... what's wrong? I am using this in one of the app...

Comment: in your given link code have the method mapView viewForOverlay: methods deprecated in ios7 so that i want to us mapView:rendererForOverlay: @Fahim Parkar